# jQuery : manipulate width and height of an img tag

Tags: jquery

How do I change the height and width of an image in and unordered list with jQuery

```
<ul id="files">
   <li><img src="1.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="2.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="3.png" />/li>
</ul>
```

My css :

```
ul#files li img
{
width: 100px;
height:100px;
}
```

I've tried this :

```
$('ul > li > img').width('300');
$('ul > li > img').height('300');
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your solution exactly ? Do you want to stretch the image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass jQuery a number for a width or height, it assumes the value is in pixels, but if you pass it a string, it *demands* a valid CSS unit. You can either say

```
$('ul > li > img').width(300);
```

or

```
$('ul > li > img').width('300px');
```

Comment: That's not the case. For strings that are only numbers jQuery attempts to convert the string to a number, then appends 'px'. width('300') is the same as width('300px').

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me.

You probably have to include these functions within `$(document).ready`, because you're currently running the code before the tags exist.

Example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul > li > img').width('300');
   $('ul > li > img').height('300');
});
</script></head><body>
<ul id="files">
   <li><img src="1.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="2.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="3.png" />/li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the jquery .css method instead

```
$('ul > li > img').css('width', '300px');
$('ul > li > img').css('height', '300px');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#files').each(function(a, b){ $(b).height(300); $(b).width(300); })
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the images a class, and select it by class doing this:

```
<img src="1.png" class="image_class">
```

Javascript:

```
$('.image_class').height('300');
$('.image_class').width('300');
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the mistake in your markup (last closing li tag missing <) your code will work as expected. You have to make sure your code is run after the document is ready though:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul > li > img').width('300');
    $('ul > li > img').height('300');
});
```

Tested with jQuery 1.6.4.